# Is Star trail photography possible on smartphone cameras

Tags: astrophotography, low-light, stars

I own a motorola G5s+ and I was wondering if we shoot video in manual mode, is it possible to have the camera record star trails. If so, what settings would be ideal? How would you change them depending on the light pollution that night.

Comment: Related: [How to take photos of planets with smartphone?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/99963)

Comment: Related: [Can I take clear night sky photographs with my smartphone?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/94814)

Comment: Related: [How to enhance a cameraphone photo so you can see stars?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/43609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an image of star trails via video, use a tripod while capturing the video. Then process the video with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org):

```
convert video.avi -evaluate-sequence max output.jpg
```

**Notes:**

- Aligning images shouldn't be necessary if a tripod is used. Stars may confuse alignment algorithm.
- No need to extract frames of video prior to processing. ImageMagick can process the video file directly.
- For [`evaluate-sequence`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#evaluate-sequence), use the `max` or `add` methods because `mean` and `median` will cause the stars to disappear.